# Sharepoint 2013 content type form edit

Tags: forms, sharepoint, content-type, sharepoint-designer

The problem is the folowing:

I have one list that shows up on 6 diferent forms using content types.
I have to show a name for each different form but have no idea how to do it.
I tryed googling but no luck there.

If I had 6 diferent forms I would solve it but i must use this because of the related workflows.

Comment: What forms? The default New / Edit / Display forms?

Comment: The ones that are showing up where I need to make the change is the New Form.

Answer (score 0):

You have 6 content types in one list ? And you want to show some name depending on content type ?

If this is your case then you can add Content Editor Web Part or Script Editor Web Part to default forms (New, Edit, Display). This web part will contain javascript code.

Javascript code on form load will get content type id query string parameter from URL and render necessary name depending on this content type id.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to your library, and from the ribbon choose **Library Settings**
- From the Settings page General Settings column choose the **Advanced Settings** Link
- From the Advanced Settings page choose the Yes radio button for the **Allow Management of Content Types** option, and then click OK
- From the Settings page, in the Content Type panel, choose **Add from Existing Content Types**
- From the Add Content Types add the Content Types you want to use on your page and click **OK**
- From the Settings page, in the Content Type panel, choose **Change new button order and default content type**
- From the Change New Button Order page ensure all your content types have the **Visible** box checked (this makes the Content Types useable in the list) and then click **OK**
- Now go back to your normal list view and from the ribbon choose **New Document** - you should see all your Content Type forms listed